# Laravel jwt authentication token expired, token_invalid

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, jwt

I have a problem with jwt auth token expiry. Here is the situation:

I have API written in laravel as one project. This API uses another laravel project (client). But when I try to log the user in, everything is fine, but then I started realizing that after TTL (60 minutes) (time to live) passes and then when I try to get user resources (which requires user to be logged in) I get the json error response {"error" => "token_expired"}.

This is the route part of the code where I use the jwt.auth middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
    Route::get('account/getUserDetails', 'Api\AccountController@getUserDetails');
});
```

I am confused why the token is not refreshing itself automatically, do I need to explicitly specify somewhere to refresh the token, I don't think so?

The 'refresh_ttl' => 20160, in the jwt.php. The endpoint looks like this:

```
public function getUserDetails(Request $request)
{

    try {
        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {

            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        $refreshed = JWTAuth::refresh(JWTAuth::getToken());
        $user = JWTAuth::setToken($refreshed)->toUser();
        return $this->response->withArray(['token' => $refreshed]);
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/872#issuecomment-253866820